# Is H8000 a stylistically differentiable sub-genre of hardcore punk?

Tags: punk, genre-characteristics

[H8000](https://vls.wikipedia.org/wiki/H8000) is often described as a sub-genre of hardcore punk from West Flanders.

What makes it a sub-genre?

- Is it only geographical? In other words, can any hardcore punk track be considered H8000 if it comes from West Flanders?
- Is it stylistic? In other words, could a listener (or even a computer algorithm) analyze a hardcore punk track and decide whether it is H8000 or not, just by listening to the track, without any other information about it?